# Preserving text formatting for dynamic website

Tags: php, content-management-system

I am facing a problem while creating a dynamic website. I am building it for some pharma company, which have many products. The problem is, every product have different sections of description, and have to be formatted differently. I wanted to store all the product descriptions in the database, but at the same time preserve the formatting of each description. I also plan to provide an admin interface, where they could edit the product information themselves.

I could use Joomla or any other CMS for that purpose, but i wanted to know if i want to build such a system of my own,  where i could format the text in an editor and them save that thing into database and when i retrieve it, i get the same formatting. How could i do this?

Also i wanted to do this in PHP.

Thanks
-- Mohit

Answer (score 1):

Just use a WYSIWYG editor like [ckEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) or [TinyMce](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/). That will handle the text formatting.. then you jsut store in your database.